# How can I delete all files that have names not ending on exactly 2 digits?

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I am currently trying to delete several files. I want to delete all files  with file names  that do not end on two digits (and when I say ending on two digits I mean it disregarding the .txt file ending).

The files are named as follows:

```
1031NAME24.txt
0709NAME16.txt
0917NAME82.txt
1106NAME9.txt
1005NAME30433.txt
0623NAME3345.txt
1005NAME112.txt
0318NAME4.txt
0112NAME78452.txt
```

In this example list all but the first three files should be deleted.

I've tried  `rm  *[!0-9][0-9]?*`, which removes all files, but those exactly ending on 1 digit (e.g "`0318NAME4.txt`, `1106NAME9.txt`") but haven't figured out how to reach my goal of keeping only files ending on exactly 2 numbers, as `rm *[!0-9][!0-9]?*` doesn't work as I want.

Comment: Formal note: in Unix/Linux what Windows calls "extension" is just a part of the name. The names you posted end with `.txt`, there is no name with digits literally at the end. I know what you *mean* though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the different methods below:

**1**

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '(.*[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3,}.[a-zA-Z]{3})|(.*[a-zA-Z][0-9].[a-zA-Z]{3})' | xargs rm
```

**2**

```
rm -fr `ls | grep -E -v '([0-9])*([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]{2})\.txt'`
```

**3**

```
rm -fr `ls | grep -E '([0-9])*([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]{3,})\..*|([0-9])*([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]{1})\..*'`
```

By the way, thee is this tool that is very helpful to learn regex:
https://regexr.com/

You can also install txt2regex (Regex build assistant):
https://aurelio.net/projects/txt2regex/

Comment: -1. This code may work for the OP but it relies on techniques that are flawed in general: [parsing `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [not quoting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). Users with similar problems will come and your code may miserably fail for them; they should be warned.

Comment: Unfortunately this code deletes files that "end" with two digits. The solution that I need should do the reverse of what this code does, and delete everything but files that "end"in  exactly two digits, but thanks for trying to help anyway

Comment: @HaskellNoob I corrected it, Please try the new one.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thank you for the link.

Comment: Frankly I expected a straightforward correction with `grep -v`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Nice one and well remembered. Thank you.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thank you for comment. Somehow I copied wrongly. I did paste the code I wanted to post yesterday and I tested it. I choose [a-zA-Z]{3} to allow to match with any extension since the Author mentioned this: "and when I say ending on two digits I mean it disregarding the .txt file ending.".

Answer (score 0):

```
find  . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '(.*[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3,}.txt)|(.*[a-zA-Z][0-9].txt)' | xargs rm
```

The first group `(.*[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3,}.txt)` gets all files that have 3 or more numbers after it. The second group `(.*[a-zA-Z][0-9].txt)` gets all files that have only 1 number after it. Leaving the files with exactly 2 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The files to keep match `*NAME[0-9][0-9].txt` pattern. You want to delete anything that does not match this.

What you need is `extglob` shell option and the pattern you are looking for will be `!(*NAME[0-9][0-9].txt)`.

Test before use. I don't know if this would match hidden files.